# Could not find gem 'rails (= 4.2.5.2) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine

Tags: ruby, redmine

I am getting the error

```
 Could not find gem 'rails (= 4.2.5.2) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine."
```

when I try to run the command **rake generate_secret_token**

Output of **gem environment**

```
RubyGems Environment:

    - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.5
    - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.8 (2015-12-16 patchlevel 440) [i386-mingw32]
    - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
    - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.exe
    - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin
    - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: C:/Users/Souvik Banerjee/.gem/specs
    - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32

GEM PATHS:

    - C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
    - C:/Users/Souvik Banerjee/.gem/ruby/2.1.0

GEM CONFIGURATION:

    - :update_sources => true
    - :verbose => true
    - :backtrace => false
    - :bulk_threshold => 1000

REMOTE SOURCES:

    - https://rubygems.org/

SHELL PATH:

    - C:\ImageMagick
    - C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
    - C:\WINDOWS\system32
    - C:\WINDOWS
    - C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
    - C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
    - C:\Program Files\nodejs\
    - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin
    - D:\apache-ant-1.9.6\bin
    - C:\Users\Souvik Banerjee\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools
    - C:\Users\Souvik Banerjee\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms
    - C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\
    - C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd
    - C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.1.0\bin
```

Output of **gem list rails**

```
C:\Sites\redmine-3.2.1>gem list rails

LOCAL GEMS

    coffee-rails (4.1.1)
    jquery-rails (4.1.0)
    rails (4.2.6, 4.2.5.1)
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
    sass-rails (5.0.4)
    sprockets-rails (3.0.1)
```

Comment: What is your environment? Please add the contents of `gem environment` and `gem list rails`.

Comment: updated as per your request.

Answer (score 3):

You have Rails version `4.2.5.1` installed, but apparently someone has updated it and now your project requires version `4.2.5.2`. Update your gems:

```
bundle install
```

Comment: I tried bundle install, but it did not work. It came back with another suggestion

    **An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.15.4), and Bundler cannot continue.**
    **Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.15.4'` succeeds before bundling.**

Comment: I assumed you had a `Gemfile`. Try to install specific version like so: `gem install rails -v 4.2.5.2`.

Comment: How to go about this?

`C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:456:in 'try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.`

`extconf failed, exit code 1`

Comment: Don't forget to install **DEVELOPMENT KIT** from [this page](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/).